# Get the total count of number of rows in the Custom Listview Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-custom-view

I am trying to getting the total Count of the getView custom listview. But want to display in the different layout. Here is my onCreatedView. I am not sure how to inflate the layout. Thanks for all your help.

```
    private static ListView addDropListView = null;
private TransactionAddDropAdapter addDropAdapter = null;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

fragmentPendingTrades = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transactions_pending, container, false);
pendingTradesView = inflater;

return fragmentPendingTrades;
}

public void onViewCreated(final View view, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

this.addDropListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.transactions_pending_transactionsListView);
this.addDropAdapter = new TransactionAddDropAdapter(pendingTradesView);
this.addDropListView.setAdapter(this.addDropAdapter);
this.emptyTransationsContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.transactions_pending_transactions_emptyContainer);



TextView getTotalCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.transactions_pending_TransactionsAddDropCount);

getTotalCount.setText(""+addDropListView.getCount());
}
```

Here is my Holderview that get the getView

```
public class TransactionAddDropAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private List<TransactionAddDrop> addDropList = new ArrayList<TransactionAddDrop>();

    public TransactionAddDropAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }

    public void setAddDropList(List<TransactionAddDrop> addDropList) {
        clearAddDropList();

        for (TransactionAddDrop ad : addDropList) {
            if (ad.isStateApprove()) {
                this.addDropApprovalsList.add(ad);
            } else {
                this.addDropList.add(ad);
            }
        }
    }

    public void clearAddDropList() {
        this.addDropList.clear();
        this.addDropApprovalsList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int size = this.addDropList.size();

        if (this.addDropApprovalsList.size() > 0) {
            size += 1;
        }

        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        try {
            if (this.addDropList == null) {
                return null;
            } else if (position < addDropList.size()) {
                return this.addDropList.get(position);
            } else {
                return this.addDropApprovalsList;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        final TransactionAddDrop addDropData = this.addDropList.get(position);



        TransactionAddDropViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pending_transaction_list_item, null);
            holder = new TransactionAddDropViewHolder();

            holder.withdrawButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.pendingTransactionItem_withdrawButton);

            holder.addContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pendingTransactionItem_addContainer);
            holder.dropContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pendingTransactionItem_dropContainer);
            holder.rootView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.swipeRight); 
            holder.swipeButtons(); 
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (TransactionAddDropViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.swipeButtons(); 
        }
}
```

Comment: First, it looks like you have code that "should" compile. I'm assuming it showing you the incorrect number of rows, right? If so, what is it showing and what are you expecting? Second, what are you attempting to do in your `getCount` method by adding one to the size?

Comment: Hi Steven, Its compiling correct. And i am getting the correct number of rows. i am just trying to display the total number of rows in the top header section. Disregard adding one to the size i am not using that anywhere.

Comment: So right now, what is it doing? Displaying "0"? nothing? some other number?

Comment: Its just displaying 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I "think" I know what's going on here. You setup your `ListView` and add its `TransactionAddDropAdapter`, and then set the total amount of items.

```
this.addDropListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.transactions_pending_transactionsListView);
this.addDropAdapter = new TransactionAddDropAdapter(pendingTradesView);
this.addDropListView.setAdapter(this.addDropAdapter);

TextView getTotalCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.transactions_pending_TransactionsAddDropCount);
getTotalCount.setText(""+addDropListView.getCount());
```

However, at this point, you haven't called `setAddDropList(List<TransactionAddDrop> addDropList)` on `addDropAdapter`, so `addDropList` in `getCount()` is still an empty array, so `getCount() == 0`, which is why you are seeing 0 being displayed.

So, you need to find where you call `addDropAdapter.setAddDropList()` and then call `getTotalCount.setText(""+addDropListView.getCount());` right after in order to update the total number of rows.

Comment: Hi Steven, Thanks for your help mate .. it worked. Looks like i need to add in the update Display after SetAddDropList. Thank you.